# HTML lists : "embedding" the bullet in the LI blocks

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Can UL/OL list bullets be embedded in the text of the LI so that instead of having two columns (left column with bullets and right column with text) there would be one single column with the text of the first line of each LI starting a few characters after the bullet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following css property for your `ul` element:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

that should do what you want.